# Tablet-PC display won't turn off when inactive

Tags: windows-7, display, power-management, touchscreen, dell-latitude

My Dell Latitude XT tablet PC display (touchscreen) won't turn off when inactive. The hard drive on this laptop died, so I installed a new hard drive. Both the old and new hard drives use(d) Windows 7. Everything works fine except for the display not turning off at the set time. In the power options, I set the display to turn off after 10 minutes. After 10 minutes, the display does indeed turn off, but then turns back on within 1-2 seconds. I have installed the latest drivers from the N-Trig website for the touchscreen and have calibrated it. It's not a mouse issue because this still happens when I unplug the mouse and use only the touchpad or nub (the XT has both). It's not a screensaver issue. When enabled, the screensaver works/turns on. But what I'm trying to do is turn off the display when the laptop is inactive. I also don't think it's a sleep mode issue. I've tried setting sleep mode to "60 minutes" and "never." The result is the same. The display still only turns off for a couple seconds, then turns back on. This cycle repeats every 10 minutes, which is the time I set for the display to turn off. I can only think that there is some program or device that keeps waking the display back up after it turns off. But I'm not sure how to tell which program or device is doing that. Any help would be appreciated.